# Optimizing an inner loop calculation in Mathematica

Tags: optimization, math, physics, wolfram-mathematica

I'm currently doing some computation in Mathematica related to Quantum Mechanics. As we've moved from a 1D to 2D lattice model, the problem size is becoming problematic

Currently, we have a summation that looks something like this:

```
corr[r1_, r2_, i_, j_] = Sum[Cos[f[x1, x2] Angle[i] r1 + f[y1, y2] Angle[j] r2], {x1, HL}, {x2, HL}, {y1, HL + 1, 2 HL}, {y2, HL + 1, 2 HL}];
```

f[. , .] is a lookup function for a pre-computed correlation function, and Angle[.] is precomputed as well.

There's no way at all to simplify this further in any way. We already took a simple optimization by converting a complex exponential (which had zero imaginary part) to the cosine expression above.

The big problem is that those HL's are based on dimension size: For linear dimension L along an axis, HL corresponds to L^d (d = 2 here). So our computation is O(n^8) in reality, neglecting the sum over i, j.

This normally isn't too bad for L = 8, if it weren't for the fact that we iterate this for 125 values of r1, and 125 of r2 to create an 125 x 125 image.

My question is: How can I most efficiently calculate this in Mathematica? I would do this in another language but there are certain problems that will make it just as slow if I tried it in something like C++.

Extra info: This is a ND-ND (number density) correlation calculation. All of the x's and  y's refer to discete points on a discrete 2D grid. The only non-discrete thing here is our r's.

Comment: Are you simply trying to compute a correlation? it seems to me that you need to find a decent, popular, well-tested library (not necessarily Mathematica one) that you can call from your code. As far as switching languages - do not jump to C++, switch to Python + SciPy.  http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/SchrodingerFDTD

Comment: Are the HL changing from one image to another?

Comment: Are `f` and `Angle` functions that have numerical definitions, or are they symbolic? Doing things numerically can make a tremendous difference. OTOH, given the size of your problem, it may be that you're just in trouble. We're talking about ~10^17 operations here.

Comment: Wouldn't you be much better off using a Monte Carlo integration scheme? They're made for this kind of problem....

Comment: @Hamish, yes this is a ND-ND correlation calculation. How well does Python + SciPy handle this compared to Mathematica? @belisarius: No HL does not change, this is for a single image only. @Pillsy, f and Angle are actually lookup functions for precomputed values. For this problem, this is how we compute the correlations. I don't believe Monte Carlo would be well suited to this.

Comment: @Sagekilla, my math bg actually is not strong enough to answer it. However, read this: http://www.vetta.org/2008/05/scipy-the-embarrassing-way-to-code/ If you like the article, then I would ask a similar question for SciPy. I am not exactly sure what is the nature of your bottleneck, but I suspect that the platform chose (Mathematica) has to do with it. I hope this is at least somewhat helpful.

Comment: Two questions:
You have i and j as both pattern variables and summation variables. Which meaning did you intend?
Also, when you say that r1 and r2 are 125x125 images, do you mean that the input will have r1 and r2 as dimension 2 arrays?

Comment: @Janus: I made a copying error. In an old version we had i, j in the summation looping to do an angle average. I fixed my question, it's meant as a parameter for the angle. Also, apologies for not being more clear: The function calculates intensity at a single point (r1, r2). This function is looped over a range of 125 x 125 values (125 r1 values, 125 r2 values) to create an image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that swapping the Fourier transform with a Cosine transform was the wrong time to optimize, as it hides the fact that this correlation calculation is really just a product of two Fourier transforms (which is the only efficient way to calculate correlations I know of).
With `ir1=Angle[i] r1` and `ir2=Angle[j] r2` your expression is equivalent to

```
Sum[Cos[f[x1, x2] ir1 + f[y1, y2] ir2], {x1, HL}, {x2, HL}, {y1, HL+1, 2 HL}, {y2, HL+1, 2 HL}]
== Re@Sum[Exp[I f[x1, x2] ir1] Exp[I f[y1, y2] ir2], {x1, HL}, {x2, HL},{y1, HL+1, 2 HL}, {y2, HL+1, 2 HL}]
== Re[corr1[ir1] corr2[ir2]]
```

where

```
corr1[ir_]:=Sum[Exp[I f[x1, x2] ir], {x1, HL}, {x2, HL}];
corr2[ir_]:=Sum[Exp[I f[y1, y2] ir], {y1, HL+1, 2 HL}, {y2, HL+1, 2 HL}];
```

As I have already cut your scaling exponent in half, I expect you are happy :), but if `f` is real-valued, you can cut another factor of two of the exponent:
In this case, we can express `corr1` as an integral over the values of `f` -- given that you can somehow get at the weight function `w`. If nothing else, you can do this numerically with a simple binning procedure.

```
corr1v2[ir_]:=Sum[ w[fval] Exp[I fval ir], {fval,fvals}],
```

which makes it clear that `corr1` is really just the Fourier transform of the weight function of `f` (so you should compute it with FFT rather than the sum above). Same goes for `corr2`.
Alternatively, if `f` is not real-valued but has enough symmetry to allow you to reparameterize in a form so `f` only depends on one of the new parameters (say, `r`,`phi`), you will also cut down the `corr1` integrals to one dimension, although it might not be a simple Fourier transform.

Comment: Thanks for the help Janus. The exact thing we're calculating looks something like this, mathematically speaking:

Sum[w[x, r] Conjugate[w[x', r]] w[y, r'] Conjugate[w[y', r']] < ConjugateTranspose[cx] cy'> <cx' ConjugateTranspose[cy]>]

Where w[x, r] is the wave function of a particle. In our case, w[x, r] happens to have the nice form of a complex exponential. I'll try what you recommend though.

Comment: I just realized I made a huge mistake. I modified my original question to have the correct summation indices. My y's were being summed over the wrong range.

Comment: I updated the answer to match -- the idea is the same. I wasn't able to match your first comment with the question right away, so consider that unread, but I added a further comment on `f` above that might be useful.